# Как при клике на кнопку удалять старые данные и загружать новые?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Данные загружаются из API, как сделать что бы при каждом клике предыдущие загруженные данные удалялись, а новые загружались?

```
$.getJSON(uri + 'ExRates/Rates/Dynamics/' + valueCurrency[0], { 'startDate': parseRuDate($('#ifrom').val()).toUTCString(), 'endDate': parseRuDate($('#ito').val()).toUTCString() })
          .done(function (data) {
              $.each(data, function (key, item) {      
                  $('<th>',{ text: JSON.stringify(item['Date'].substr(0,10)) }).appendTo($('#res'));            
                  $('<td>',{ text: JSON.stringify(item['Cur_OfficialRate']) }).appendTo($('#usd'));
                 console.log(item)
                    
              });
              $('#btn').removeAttr("disabled");
          });
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Сформулируйте вопрос точнее , пожалуйста. Удалять откуда? Со страницы?  Что значит новые? У вас пагинация и вы данные извлекаете со смещением? Это уже зависит от конкретного API .

Comment: @МихаилРебров, данные заношу в html таблицу  при клике и надо, что бы при следующем клике данные из таблицы удалялись и добавлялись новые.
пример кода добавил в вопрос.

Comment: `$("#res, #usd").empty()` сделайте перед добавлением.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` тут кажется лишним у вас

Comment: @teran, если добавить empty() то вообще ни чего не загружает на страницу

Comment: это смотря куда вы это добавили